# Cannot load logstash config file on kubernetes

Tags: java, spring, docker, kubernetes, logstash

I'm trying to deploy logstash to kubernetes. Before I was running it by docker compose and it was working. On compose i have:

```
    volumes:
  - ./logstash/config/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml:ro
  - ./logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline:ro
```

To deploy it on kubernetes I created dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash-oss:6.2.3
ADD ./config/logstash.yml /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml:ro
ADD ./pipeline /usr/share/logstash/pipeline:ro
```

But after run that image logstash doesn't see the config file. (Even locally)

Comment: where are your running the `docker build` from?

Comment: I'm in logstash dir.  There is Dockerfile and two folders config and pipeline. I think paths to files are good. The problem probably is with ADD command.

Comment: Have you tried `COPY` ?

Comment: Yes COPY and VOLUME too. Resoult is the same. I will try use ADD and in ENTRYPOINT use longstash -f pathToConfig

Answer (score 1):

That Dockerfile works fine for me:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash-oss:6.2.3
RUN rm -f /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
ADD pipeline/ /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/
ADD config/ /usr/share/logstash/config/
```

I think before the problem was with overriding the logstash.conf file